# object-fit: cover doesn't work properly with <object> in Chrome

Tags: html, css, svg, object-fit

I'm trying to make an `<object>` full screen, with the `object-fit: cover;` property, but unfortunately in Chrome the result is contain, instead of cover. In Firefox I get the result what I'm looking for. I tried it with `<img>` tag, and it works, but I can't use an animated svg without `<object>`.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: calc(80vh - 100px);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

object {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://svgur.com/i/asr.svg" />
</div>
```

How can I get the same result in Chrome?

Comment: I would use the svg as a backroud. Then you are free to apply background-size.

Comment: I think it won't work with animated svg.